# Create Twitter List Widget

Tags: wordpress, twitter-feed

I can't code. How can I create a Twitter widget to show tweets from a Twitter list?

I want to use it on my blog. On the left side widget area of a static home page. Ideally I'd like more than just text. I'd like a bubble graphic around each tweet.

Also there's over 4k people on the list so it would be good to show only tweets that have been faved or RTed.

This is hoping for too much right? I'll settle for just a simple widget to start off with. Do you know of plug-ins that do that?

I believe the code for the widget should be just one line.

https://twitter.com/Dev_4iOS/lists/geeks-who-know-their-shit is the URL to the list. I tried creating an RSS feed but didn't figure it out.

Thanks.

Edit: I also want to add a subscribe button for the list.

Comment: "I believe the code for the widget should be just one line." LOL. No, that's unlikely.

Comment: My downvote was for not putting "twitter widget" into Google.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter offers a few pre-built widgets - the closest to what you want is the [List widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/list). You're pretty limited in customizing its look/feel/functionality - chances are you're not going to get your bubble graphics or filter by stars.

Comment: @ConorNolan It works fine. Chances are you have to be logged in. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iSBBT.png